# How to pass header in hasura-session?

Tags: postgresql, hasura, hasura-docker, hasura-jwt

I am running a hasura project and I am using compute field in hasura.
How can I pass and get the header in the query?
There is already an open issue, but people are talking about a workaround as well but it didn't work out for me.

Here is header:
x-hasura-preferred-lang: de_de

Here is the query

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.interest_translation_function(interest_row interest, hasura_session json)
 RETURNS text
 LANGUAGE sql
 STABLE
AS $function$
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN (hasura_session ->> 'x-hasura-preferred-lang' = 'en_us' AND T.en_us IS NOT NULL) THEN T.en_us
        WHEN (hasura_session ->> 'x-hasura-preferred-lang' = 'de_de' AND T.de_de IS NOT NULL) THEN T.de_de
        ELSE T.source
    END
FROM i18n T
WHERE T.source = interest_row.name;
$function$
```

You can see for now I am using hasura_session which we will get from jwt, but I want to pass the header without jwt. any though on this

I am expecting to get translated value without passing token when the same table has permission

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any solution. There seems to be an [open issue](https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/1601) for this.
I end up with the below approach.

1. You can pass language code in the Hasura mutation without creating any new action.
   You can update compute field sql like below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.interest_translation_function(interest_row interest, lang_code text)
 RETURNS text
 LANGUAGE sql
 STABLE
AS $function$
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN (lang_code = 'en_us' AND T.en_us IS NOT NULL) THEN T.en_us
        WHEN (lang_code = 'de_de' AND T.de_de IS NOT NULL) THEN T.de_de
        ELSE T.source
    END
FROM i18n T
WHERE T.source = interest_row.name;
$function$
```

2. Query will look something like this.

```
query GetInterest {
  interest {
    name
    translated(args: {lang_code: "de_de"})
  }
}
```